# How to delete a specifc pattern from a string using awk or perl?

Tags: linux, awk, perl

How to delete only `[gene=xyzI]` pattern if I have multiple entries like this:

`>lcl|NZ_CP018664.1_gene_628 [gene=mscL] [locus_tag=AUO97_RS03160] [location=complement(694895..695326)]`

I want my output to be:

`>lcl|NZ_CP018664.1_gene_628 [locus_tag=AUO97_RS03160] [location=complement(694895..695326)]`

Answer (score 2):

For simple substitution - **`sed`** would be enough:

```
sed -E 's/\[gene=[a-z]{3}[A-Z]\] *//' file
```

The output:

```
>lcl|NZ_CP018664.1_gene_628 [locus_tag=AUO97_RS03160] [location=complement(694895..695326)]
```

---

To modify file *"inplace"* - add `-i` option: `sed -i ....`

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU awk`:

```
$ echo '>lcl|NZ_CP018664.1_gene_628 [gene=mscL] [locus_tag=AUO97_RS03160] [location=complement(694895..695326)]'  | awk '{$0=gensub(/\s*\S+/,"",2)}1'
>lcl|NZ_CP018664.1_gene_628 [locus_tag=AUO97_RS03160] [location=complement(694895..695326)]
```

It can be also done with `cut`:

```
$ echo '>lcl|NZ_CP018664.1_gene_628 [gene=mscL] [locus_tag=AUO97_RS03160] [location=complement(694895..695326)]'  | cut -d' ' -f1,3-
>lcl|NZ_CP018664.1_gene_628 [locus_tag=AUO97_RS03160] [location=complement(694895..695326)]
```